# Enabling disabled days Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

In Bootstrap 3 Datepicker, there is an `daysOfWeekDisabled` option which I can disable all the cells from that column like this:

[image]

In that case I did this:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es',
    inline: true,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0] // This one makes Sunday disabled from clicking 
});
```

My question: Is there a way to enable a day that was already disabled?
For example: I already disabled all days from Sunday, but I want specifically "20 August" to be enabled so I can click on it.

Comment: you might have to populate `disabledDates: []` array with dates that you want to disable

Comment: i was thinking the same but the fact that we alredy have an option who can disable all the column, i believe it was way easier than just creating an array.